# Using my Apache2 www folder on a USB drive: PERMISSION DENIED

Tags: usb, raspbian-stretch, apache-httpd

My Raspian Apache2 does not seem to like the www folder on a RAspberry-3B USB drive, which I can easily access from my Windows network.
It keeps giving me
***You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) Server at 192.168.200.99 Port 80***
All works OK however if the **/var/www** folder is used. And even PHP works OK.
 My (abbreviated) setup is as follows-
FSTAB:

```
UUID=1375-E205 /media/USBdrive32 vfat auto,sync,umask=000,gid=root,uid=root,rw 0 0
```

I can easily access this from Windows+Samba.
The Apache conf file is as follows-

```
##### <Directory /var/www/>  
<Directory **/media/USBdrive32/www/**>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

the usb has the following permissions:  (sample)
 **drwxrwxrwx  6 root root**  16384 Sep  1 14:00
 I have tried changing this to  u= (me) g=www-data, but the same results are obtained.
Ideally, once this working, I'd like to change the whole USB media drive, or at least the www folder on it, to  umask=004 or perhaps even 007.
 I can edit the www folder from my Windows Notepad++   But Apache will not allow me to use it as a LAMP webserver.
Any ideas on where my ***403 forbidden problem*** is?

Comment: Why not change the uid & gid on your mount command to www-data as that's what Apache2 runs with.

Comment: Been there, done that.  i.e .  User= (me) group=www-data.    Ahh.  I have not tried USER as www-data   .... but the /var/html    uses  root and root.  So why does it work OK?

Comment: Nope.       UUID=1375-E205 /media/USBdrive32 vfat auto,sync,umask=000,gid=www-data,uid=www-data,rw 0 0     
 does not work either....

Comment: What shows up in /var/log/apache2/error.log when you get the 403?

Comment: AHA!      
[Thu Feb 28 22:53:29.873091 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5711] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Feb 28 22:53:29.873281 2019] [core:notice] [pid 5711] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Feb 28 22:54:14.692808 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 5729] [client 192.168.200.63:50309] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
     
Somewhere it is still looking at   /var/www... it must be something in an include in the .conf folder-  I'll look at it...

Comment: This is not a question belonging to Raspberry Pi. Please ask for Apache2 configuration at https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: The will never work for the same reason as in [ownCloud setup: Can't write into config directory!](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48126/owncloud-setup-cant-write-into-config-directory). FAT32 doesn't support UNIX permissions which are needed by Apache.

Comment: Never work? REALLY? Well... I finally got it to work. See my answer below. And I am using FAT32 USB drives.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache webserver used to have almost all its parameters in the parent file:  **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**
Now it's a case of modifying its includes.
In this case, specifically the **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-conf** file, which now contains the **`<VirtualHost *:80>`**
 The last time I used this (six months ago!), it was in its parent apache2.conf

Its **DocumentRoot parameter must be changed** from the  /var/www/html/  to the FAT32 USB media file as set up in the fstab.
E.G. **DocumentRoot /media/USBdrive32/www**

All is OK now. Apache2 can access the www folder, AND I can edit it with either Windows-10 or Linux.